# `shouldComponentUpdate` switches props and state when comparing `nextProps` and `nextState`

Tags: reactjs

Here is my method:

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextState, nextProps) => {
    return nextState.numMonthsToShow !== this.state.numMonthsToShow;
}
```

I'm getting `undefined` when I log `nextState.numMonthsToShow`, so after looking into it, it looks like the component is actually confusing `nextProps` and `nextState`.

Here are my log statements.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKdR7.png)

And here is where those statements are being logged:

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextState, nextProps) => {
    console.log('props:', this.props);
    console.log('nextProps:', nextProps);
    console.log('state:', this.state);
    console.log('nextState:', nextState);
    return nextState.numMonthsToShow !== this.state.numMonthsToShow;
  }
```

Can anybody help me explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong use
`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` instead of `shouldComponentUpdate(nextState, nextProps)`

Comment: Hey that worked, thank you! Didn't realize I was passing in the wrong parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Order of arguments in a JS function is important. As per [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), the proper signature of the `shouldComponentUpdate` is `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`.

To achieve the desired outcome, you need to interchage the argument names in your function:

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    return nextState.numMonthsToShow !== this.state.numMonthsToShow;
}
```